Can't install make on MSYS2 MinGW x86 shell : mingw-w64-i686-gettext-runtime-0.22.5-2 and mingw-w64-i686-gettext-0.21-3 are in conflict
I want to install a c++-Compiler and make in the MSYS2 MinGW x86 shell
So I open this shell and type
MINGW32> pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-make

I get the output
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: mingw-w64-i686-gettext-runtime and mingw-w64-i686-gettext are in conflict. Remove mingw-w64-i686-gettext? [Y/n] Y
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing mingw-w64-i686-gettext breaks dependency 'mingw-w64-i686-gettext' required by mingw-w64-i686-glib2
:: removing mingw-w64-i686-gettext breaks dependency 'mingw-w64-i686-gettext' required by mingw-w64-i686-libtre-git
:: removing mingw-w64-i686-gettext breaks dependency 'mingw-w64-i686-gettext' required by mingw-w64-i686-p11-kit
:: removing mingw-w64-i686-gettext breaks dependency 'mingw-w64-i686-gettext' required by mingw-w64-i686-xz

This is the ouput , if I say no instead of yes to the above question
imelf@DESKTOP-CFHKUQA MINGW32 ~
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-make
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: mingw-w64-i686-gettext-runtime-0.22.5-2 and mingw-w64-i686-gettext-0.21-3 are in conflict. Remove mingw-w64-i686-gettext? [Y/n] n
error: unresolvable package conflicts detected
error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)
:: mingw-w64-i686-gettext-runtime-0.22.5-2 and mingw-w64-i686-gettext-0.21-3 are in conflict (mingw-w64-i686-gettext<=0.22.4-3)

It is the same output , if I try to install the C++-Compiler with the command
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gcc

I get the same errors with this gettext (which I don't know anything about)
I tried to update all the packages with
pacman -Suy

and then I tried again, but it was of no use.
Any help appreciated!

Just update gettext with the command:
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gettext

After that you can install whatever you were trying to.
